# Convert Entity Collection to Ilist where Entity Collection does not implement IEnumerable

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I have a `Entity` Collection Like this:
**EntityCollection** users;

I want to convert it to a `Ilist` like this:

```
systemUsers = new List<CrmSdkTypeProxy.SystemUser>();
```

where `CrmSdkTypeProxy.SystemUser` is a type of `Entity`. However, my `Entity` Collection is derived from a `dll` of `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk` which does not implement `IEnumerable`. I am using `mscrm` 2011 specific `dlls`.

Any idea on how I create a list like this: `.List<CrmSdkTypeProxy.SystemUser>`?

Comment: What about using the `EntityCollection.Entities` property which is a `DataCollection<T>` which is inherited from `Collection<T>`?

Comment: Sorry i deleted my answer, because i misunderstood your question.

Comment: @nemesv..how do i change DataCollection<T> to IList<SystemUser>?

Answer (score 3):

from what I gather from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entitycollection_members.aspx and the top of my head:

```
var myList = (from t in myEntityCollection.Entities select t as CRMSDKTypeProxy.SystemUser).ToList();
```

and linq-less:

```
var myList = new List<CRMSDKTypeProxy.SystemUser>(myEntityCollection.Entities);
```

Comment: I could use it like this:var myList = new List<Entity>(users.Entities); But my actual requirement was :var myList = new List<CRMSDKTypeProxy.SystemUser>(users.Entities);

Comment: I thought that it was implied with "MyEntity" that you could really put any entity type you like in there. But to be very very clear ill update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

Entities is a `DataCollection<Entity>` which you can convert into an `IEnumerable` and then use the `ToList` function to create your List which matches the `IList` interface that you require.

```
return service.RetrieveMultiple(query)
                                .Entities
                                .Select(item => item.ToEntity<SystemUser>())
                                .ToList<SystemUser>();
```

Comment: I think this is the correct and best answer. ToEntity<T>() is the SDK built-in method to do the conversion.

Comment: ToEntity<T>() is in fact doing a shallow copy.

Answer (score 0):

Finally...iterated through the DataCollection and added individual values to the Ilist