# How to cast an Xrm.EntityCollection to a List?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, fetchxml

**Overview:**

I'm coding a FetchXML query to return users with disabled mailboxes in a Dynamics 2015 online CRM instance. Now I've come to a stage where the query results need to be bound to a ListView. (The project is using the [Dynamics SDK 2015 libs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=44567).)

In order to do this I've tried to cast the returned result which is an `EntityCollection` -> to a list. But the `CRMSDKTypeProxy` can't be found in my code for the cast.

I was following this example's second answer in order to do the casting:

[Convert Entity Collection to Ilist where Entity Collection does not implement IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132075/convert-entity-collection-to-ilist-where-entity-collection-does-not-implement-ie)

**Question:**

Does anyone know how to reference the CRMSDKTypeProxy? Or any alternative way to cast my collection to a list?

**Code: (short example)**

```
if (ctrl.CrmConnectionMgr != null && ctrl.CrmConnectionMgr.CrmSvc != null && ctrl.CrmConnectionMgr.CrmSvc.IsReady)
{
    CrmServiceClient svcClient = ctrl.CrmConnectionMgr.CrmSvc;
    if (svcClient.IsReady)
    {
        // Get data from CRM . 
        string DisabledMailBoxUsersFetchXML =
            @"<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
                <entity name='systemuser'>
                <attribute name='fullname' />
                <attribute name='businessunitid' />
                <attribute name='title' />
                <attribute name='address1_telephone1' />
                <attribute name='positionid' />
                <attribute name='systemuserid' />
                <order attribute='fullname' descending='false' />
                <link-entity name='mailbox' from='mailboxid' to='defaultmailbox' alias='aa'>
                    <filter type='and'>
                    <condition attribute='statecode' operator='eq' value='1' />
                    </filter>
                </link-entity>
                </entity>
            </fetch>";

        var DisabledMailBoxUsersResult = svcClient.GetEntityDataByFetchSearchEC(DisabledMailBoxUsersFetchXML);

        if (DisabledMailBoxUsersResult != null)
        {
            //perform the cast here --->
            var disabledMailBoxUsersList = (from t in DisabledMailBoxUsersResult.Entities select t as CRMSDKTypeProxy.SystemUser).ToList();
            disabledMailboxUserLBx.ItemsSource = disabledMailBoxUsersList;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("All user's mailboxes are approved..");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `ToEntity<T>` method to do the conversion to a strong typed entity like this: (In this snippet `service` is an object implementing the `IOrganizationService` interface and `query` is a `QueryExpression` object.)

```
// RetrieveMultiple will never return null, so this one-liner is safe to use.
var userList = service.RetrieveMultiple(query)
    .Entities
    .Select(e => e.ToEntity<SystemUser>())
    .ToList();
```

I noticed you are using the `CrmServiceClient` in the `Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector` namespace. This was introduced in Dynamics CRM 2013.

Your code could look like this:

```
var userList = svcClient.OrganizationServiceProxy
    .RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchXml))
    .Entities
    .Select(e => e.ToEntity<SystemUser>())
    .ToList();
```

and alternatively this should work too:

```
var userList = svcClient.GetEntityDataByFetchSearchEC(fetchXml)
    .Entities
    .Select(e => e.ToEntity<SystemUser>())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I tried adapting that code to mine but there is no definition for RetrieveMultiple. This is what I tried:                     `var userList = svcClient.RetrieveMultiple(DisabledMailBoxUsersFetchXML).Entities.Select(e => e.ToEntity<SystemUser>());`    Any ideas what the issue is there?

Comment: I overlooked the fact you are using the `Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector` namespace. Extended my answer.

Comment: Okay is the SystemUser type a model class I need to add?

Comment: In your code sample you are using `CRMSDKTypeProxy.SystemUser`. It is a so called "early bound" entity class that can be generated with the CrmSvcUtil.exe tool. This tool is part of the Dynamics CRM SDK.

Comment: Do you perhaps know if you can return an anonymous list? Something like `.Select(e => e.ToEntity<T>()).ToList();`

Comment: @VDWWD, yes, you can use generics here as well.

Answer (score 2):

@Henk van Boeijen is partially correct. Rather than use the service.Retrieve in his example replace it with your svcClient.GetEntityDataByFetchSearchEC(DisabledMailBoxUsersFetchXML) call.

```
var userList = svcClient.GetEntityDataByFetchSearchEC(DisabledMailBoxUsersFetchXML).Entities.Select(e => e.ToEntity<SystemUser>());
```

If your'e not using the early bound entities then you can simply call .ToList() on the Entity collection.

```
var userList = svcClient.GetEntityDataByFetchSearchEC(DisabledMailBoxUsersFetchXML).Entities.ToList();
```

The Entities property of the EntityCollection is a DataCollection which extends the Collection object and you can call the usual methods.

Comment: Okay can you clarify where the SystemUser type is coming from?

Comment: Are you using the entities generated with the CRMSVCUtil?

Comment: Okay didn't know about this tool. I'll look that up first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689217/systemuser-class-in-crm2011-sdk-sample-code

Comment: So the following should work if using ToList() ? http://hastebin.com/minonicoki.avrasm

Comment: I don't see any reason that wouldn't work. I'm not at a location where I can test it.